# Is it possible to dynamically create a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

For example: an UITextView will be created when a touch event happens.

How to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

You'll have to do this programmatically, I don't think this is possible in Interface Builder.

Just do something like

```
UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
myTextView.text = @"some text";
//some other setup like setting the font for the UITextView...
[self addSubview:myTextView];
[myTextView sizeToFit];
```

in the appropriate method of you view (e.g. `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`) or your view controller.

Answer (score 9):

```
UITextView*txtview =
    [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,hight)];  
[txtview setDelegate:self];    
[txtview setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];    
[txtview setTag:1];    
[txtview setCornerRadius:5];    
[self.scrollview txtview];
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift

```
let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(x,y,width,height))
textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
textView.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
self.view.addSubview(textView)
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 4.x**

```
let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50)
let textView = UITextView(frame: frame)
textView.textAlignment = .center
view.addSubview(textView)
```